# PHP Warning: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel

I'm using hosting in linux and configured subdomain in my website in Apache2 server. I'm using laravel but I didn't use apache2 service by default. I'm using laravel artisan commands.

> php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0

It will listen to port 8000. So in order to access my website, I'm used http://myipaddress:8000 to access it.

I tried to "chmod 755 or 777 public folder" but still didn't work. My .htaccess in laravel/public folder

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

When I access my website with port 8000, below is my errors:

```
PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required 'server.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/php/PEAR') in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: when you `$ php artisan serve` you got an error? What is error exactly? Please describe step by step!

Comment: When I artsian serve, there is not error, as usual that Laravel started on http://0.0.0.0:8000. Until I access my link http://myip:8000, errors started generate like mention above. @SetKyarWaLar

Comment: try this one  `php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0`

Comment: @mininoz Makes no difference with php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0

Comment: Does server.php exist?

Comment: Maybe your RewriteEngine is not working or giving back wrong information. Try to deactivate it (RewriteEngine Off) or just rename the .htaccess for testing.

Comment: @Jeemusu Nope, I can't find it in laravel directory

Comment: @FlowCastv It should be in the /app/ directory. If it's not there, that could be the problem. If it is there, make sure it has the correct permissions.

Comment: @Jeemusu I created a new server.php as in app folder from https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/server.php. Make the sudo chmod 777 permission, but errors still occur as mentions above.

Comment: If your server.php wasn't there to begin with, who knows what else isn't there. Is it an older version of Laravel or a clean install? Have you tried doing a chmod on all the directories, not just the public? 

All I can advise is to [check that PEAR is installed](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.checking.php).

Comment: I'm using Laravel 4.2, this is not clean install. I'm pulled my sources from github... Yes, I chmod 777 everything in the folder, the errors still occur. Perhaps is not Laravel problem ?

Comment: if you pulled from github so there might be chance of missing file , Plz check git_ignore file.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old question, but I was having the same problem and I found a solution by adding a `server.php` file to the *root directory* of the project with the following content:

```
<?php
$uri = urldecode(
    parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
);

// This file allows us to emulate Apache's "mod_rewrite" functionality from the
// built-in PHP web server. This provides a convenient way to test a Laravel
// application without having installed a "real" web server software here.
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri))
{
    return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, the real cause of the problem is this, somewhere along the line, the last parameter for the `php -S` built in server was changed to a flag, so you have to call it like this:

`php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public -f serve.php`

Before php 7.0.26 you could omit the `-f`.

This is what happens under the hood when you call `php artisan serve`.

If you want to serve it with `php artisan serve` you will have to override the `ServeCommand` and add `-f` before the `serve.php` ont the last line of the `fire()` method, like this:

`passthru('"'.PHP_BINARY.'"'." -S {$host}:{$port} -t \"{$public}\" -f server.php");`

For more details look at this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47670251/php-artisan-serve-require-fatal-error-after-upgrading-php7/47680522#47680522).

Comment: I hit this after the security update yesterday to 7.0.28 on Ubuntu 16.04, thanks :-)

Comment: Glad it helped you, when I encountered this I wanted to pull my hair out :D