# Php artisan serve require fatal error after upgrading php7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, php-7

After upgrading php from 7.0.14 to 7.0.26 `php artisan serve` throws this error

> Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   Unknown on line 0
>       Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/school-dashboard/public/server.php'
>   (include_path='.:') in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Did you check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/37277510/2815635

Comment: Yes I tried it and it works, but In my opinion that's just a workaround, not a real solution :/

Comment: did you change your php path in environment ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, after hours of pulling my hair out I finally found out what the issue was.

In laravel 4 `php artisan serve` does this under the hood

```
<?php 

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;

class ServeCommand extends Command {

   public function fire()
   {
       $this->checkPhpVersion();

       chdir($this->laravel['path.base']);

       $host = $this->input->getOption('host');

       $port = $this->input->getOption('port');

       $public = $this->laravel['path.public'];

       $this->info("Laravel development server started on http://{$host}:{$port}");

       passthru('"'.PHP_BINARY.'"'." -S {$host}:{$port} -t \"{$public}\" server.php");
    }
}
```

That is essentially this in plain php:
`php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public serve.php` - [see the docs for php built in server for more info](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php).

And this worked well and dandy before php 7.0.26, where the last parameter for the `php -S` built in server was changed to a flag as well, so you have to call it like this `php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public -f serve.php`.

If you want to serve it with `php artisan serve` you will have to override  the `ServeCommand` and change the last line of the `fire()` method to this:

`passthru('"'.PHP_BINARY.'"'." -S {$host}:{$port} -t \"{$public}\" -f server.php");`

Or you can change it directly in the `ServeCommand`, but if you do a composer update or install you will have to do it again.

Answer (score 0):

That's what it happened to me today running a Laravel project. After i have tried all the possible solutions finally i got one that it's work for me . So first of all check that your anti-virus block your server.php and it also deleting it . Then check if you server.php is missing from your project, and I think that is  probably yes . Just copy it (server.php) from other project (build also from laravel)  but before that just turn off your anti-virus until your next restart and make you sure that you will stop it every time before running. I hope that it helps you.